# Make content inside scrollView match display size

Tags: android, layout

I have a `ScrollView` with a `RelativeLayout` inside it.

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/toWrap"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/background_color">
```

I want to make this RelativeLayout **not** fill its parent, but fill the **display**.

I want that because when I open the keyboard, the layout gets ugly.

I've tried to create a `ExpandableRelativeLayout` subclass with onDraw like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    DisplayMetrics metrics = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();

    setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, (int)(metrics.heightPixels * metrics.density)));

    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

But I constantly received this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(15331): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams`
```

How do I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use **RelativeLayout.LayoutParams** instead of layoutparams. That what I always do and didnot have any errors. Also if you are using ecllipse and you altered the xml and this error occured after that then you should close ecllipse and start again. This is a bug in ecllipse where at some point your R.java stops generating and classcastexception occurs.

Comment: That solved the error, but not the problem. When the keyboard appears, the view collapses.

Comment: @MaurícioGiordano for matching the screen width and height you need to override onmeasure